# Async void or Task.Run?

Tags: c#, async-await

Consider this method:

```
public Status SendMessage(InParam inParam)
{
    try
    {
        Task.Run(() => MethodAsync(inParam));
        return Status.Success;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception
        return Status.Failed;
    }
}
```

The MethodAsync method:

```
public async Task<Status> MethodAsync(InParam inParam)
{
    try
    {
        return await processor.Process(inParam);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log exception
        return Status.Failed;
    }
}
```

and the Process method:

```
public async Task<Status> Process(InParam inParam)
{
    try
    {
         IMessage endpoint = (IMessage)Activator
            .CreateInstance(Type.GetType(_message.AgentDLLName), args);
         _messageDispatchers.Add(endpoint);

        foreach (IMessage dispatcher in _messageDispatchers)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => dispatcher.SendMessage(_message));
        }
        return await Task.Run(() => Status.Success);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log exception
        return Status.Failed;
    }

}
```

So the use case is that at the end of some processing workflow an email has to be sent.
This email sending part was taking some time and the user had to wait, so the original developer put this code.

I am trying to make SendMessage call MethodAsync and should not wait for it to return.
I have read that in an async workflow the complete stack needs to be async for it to work properly. The SendMessage is not marked async.

Is this the correct way to call MethodAsync since Task.Run returns an awaitable?

Comment: `return await Task.Run(() => Status.Success);` - that line looks like it should just be `return Status.Success`, no?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That one is actually in the production code and not a typo by me. I have added the for loop now in the question which I missed earlier.

Comment: @Codehelp: Still does not make any sense. `return await Task.Run(() => Status.Success);` results in exactly the same logic as `return Status.Success;`, but will cause an additional context-switch which just wastes CPU-time...

Comment: @ChrFin point noted. Will make the change. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As `MethodAsync` is marked as `async` the call `Task.Run(() => MethodAsync(inParam));` does not make much sense.
If you want to implement it as a "*fire-and-forget*"-call (**BAD by the way**) you can simply call `MethodAsync(inParam);`, because this also starts the `await`ed method inside `MethodAsync` "in its own task" (simplified) and returns that. If you then do not "wait that awaitable" your code inside `SendMessage` will continue to execute while it is still running.

BUT as already said: "*fire-and-forget*" is bad design in almost all cases. Can you explain your use-case a little more, so we may can provide a better approach?

*UPDATE:*
If there is REALLY no way to either make `SendMessage` `async` or have a synchronous counterpart of `MethodAsync` I recommend the following:

```
public Status SendMessage(InParam inParam)
{
    try
    {
        return AsyncPump.Run(() => MethodAsync(inParam));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception
        return Status.Failed;
    }
}
```

Using the [`AsyncPump`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/02/10263555.aspx) you can return "the real result" and have no deadlocking problems.
In your example implementation of `SendMessage` the `try`/`catch` also makes less sense, as the method will very likely return way before any exeption will happen inside `MethodAsync`.

**UPDATE 2** (after updated question):
I would recommend "going `async` all the way". Meaning also make `SendMessage` `async` (and all methods up to the UI) so you can `await` the "real result", but do not lock the UI while you are waiting...

*UPDATE 3:*
I would also change

```
foreach (IMessage dispatcher in _messageDispatchers)
{
    await Task.Run(() => dispatcher.SendMessage(_message));
}
```

to

```
await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach (IMessage dispatcher in _messageDispatchers)
            dispatcher.SendMessage(_message);
    });
```

This casues less context-switches. Or even:

```
await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(_messageDispatchers, d => d.SendMessage(_message)));
```

Comment: appreciate your time and answer. The process is triggered from an MVC app so locking the UI won't happen I guess! No?

Comment: @Codehelp: Ah, MVC. No, there no "UI is locking", but the request will not complete. Take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx to run it in the background. But you will always "lose the result" if you do not wait for it...

Comment: This _"async all the way"_ virus is starting to smell of cargo cult. Overhaul your codebase for....reasons. `TaskCompletionSource` can help you fake an `async` method with legacy code with very little messing around.